# Printing a string results in (Function) in console. Why?

Tags: swift, base64, alamofire, basic-authentication

I'm trying to create a base64 basic authentication header for use with an API. In swift 2.0 and iOS9 it's started to give me problems, so I'd like to examine the contents of headers or base64Credentials. Unfortunately, all I see is (Function).

```
    let credentialData = "demo@demo.com:demo123".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions  

    let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"]

    print("Here are the base64 encoded headers \(base64Credentials)")
```

Yields

Here are the base64 encoded headers (Function)

How can I figure out what the values of these strings are?

Am I missing something new in Swift 2.0 that has suddenly made this a problem?

Thank you,

Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public func base64EncodedStringWithOptions(options: NSDataBase64EncodingOptions) -> String
```

is an instance *method*. Functions and methods are called with
zero or more arguments in parentheses. In this case we have one
argument, which can be `[]` for no options:

```
let credentialData = "demo@demo.com:demo123".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])  

print("Here are the base64 encoded headers \(base64Credentials)")
// Here are the base64 encoded headers ZGVtb0BkZW1vLmNvbTpkZW1vMTIz
```

In your code

```
let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions
```

the method itself is assigned to the variable, and that prints
as "(Function)".

> Am I missing something new in Swift 2.0 that has suddenly made this a problem?

No, this would be the same issue in Swift 1.2. The only difference
is the *type* of the parameter, in Swift 1.2 you would specify
"no options" as `nil` instead of `[]`.

Comment: This was spot on. We were giving it nil but as of 2.0 that wasn't right so we ended up getting rid of it which lead to this problem. Thanks for the help! Great explanation.